# Varnish cache subdirectories using regex

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

Using Varnish 4 I'm trying to cache a specific style of url: one with a certain number of directories:

```
if (req.url ~ "(?Ui)^/cars/.+/.+/.+/$") {
  return(hash);
}
```

This should MATCH the following:

```
/cars/only/four/subdirectories/
/cars/a/b/c/
```

However, it should not match these:

```
/cars/not/five/sub/directories/
/cars/not/four/and/some.html
/cars/not/three/
/cars/not_two/
```

However, the code I have seems to match anything with a trailing /  <strike>(effectively `^/cars/.*/$`)</strike>. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: a bit of further testing and I was wrong about the 'effectively' part. It seems to match four or more directories - only those that end in a trailing /

Comment: What is it matching from the second list? All of them except `some.html`?

Comment: It matches `/cars/not/five/sub/directories/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to make `.` match anything other than `/`, so it would make sense to define it that way:

```
"(?Ui)^/cars/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/$"
```

Otherwise, it matches anything (including `/`).

Comment: I could have sworn I tried something along those lines, but this works perfectly. Thanks!